# SAPUI5 - Input Field - Fontsize - CSS: Changing fontsize does not work

Tags: css, sapui5, font-size, input-field

I have a field of type sap.m.Input.
I placed it in my view as we all know it.
I added my custom .css code which looks like this:

```
.inputFocused{

  background-color: #ABEBC6 !important;
  font-size: 3.5rem !important; 
}

.inputNotFocused{

    background-color: #F4F4F4 !important;
    font-size: 35px !important;
 }
```

No matter, whether I pass one of those styles as tag-attribute via

```
<Input class="inputNotFocused" id="privateId" type="Number" editable="false" maxLength="13" placeholder="{i18n>privateId}" width="150px"/>
```

or if I do it at runtime at any given moment, like

```
this.rInputWithFocus.addStyleClass("inputFocused");
```

I do see the change in the background-color.

BUT never ever the font changed.

The same approach works, e.g, for simple labels, without any issues.

But apparently not for sap.m.Input.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI5 control `Input` will be rendered as a div which contains the actual input.

The resulting HTML will look like the following

```html
<div id="__xmlview1--inputText-content" class="sapMInputBaseContentWrapper" style="width: 100%;">
    <input id="__xmlview1--inputText-inner" placeholder="Enter text" value="" aria-labelledby="__label5" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="sapMInputBaseInner">
</div>
```

Your custom class `inputNotFocused` will be applied to the div.

The inner input has its own CSS class which defines a different font-size (but not a different background-color, that's why the background-color can be changed by changing the div and the input will inherit the background-color from the div).

If you want to change the inner input, adapt your CSS:

```css
.inputNotFocused input {
   font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

or use `.inputNotFocused .sapMInputBaseInner` as the selector.

No need for ugly `!important` btw.

**But keep in mind, adding your own CSS to SAP standard CSS may break in the future.**

Comment: Thx  a lot. I did similar stuff to my buttons, as I wanted to have them bigger, with a bigger font and so on. I jumoed in "onAfterRenderingh", picked the domRef and changed two inner spans for that. I Thought, I can avoid this apporach for the Input field, but it does not seem like that.

Basically SAP made an absolutely horrible job with their wrapper around controls and their properties, I mean, what did they want to achieve with this useless limitations ? 

What were they thinking by developing this stupid nonsense ? 
I have seen a lot of nonsense, but this just tops it off.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "limitation". The controls are easily extendable if you know CSS. I also don't know why they created wrappers for controls where it doesn't seem necessary but if you stick to the standard (and the SAP Fiori Design Guidelines exist for a reason) then you shouldn't have to worry about internal details anyway.

Comment: Apparently i need to worry...  1 ) overwriting standard css with local ones will apply this for ALL controls, which use a certain standard css. This is not what I want. 2) Some buttons, for example, shall have bold font, bigger font, and be a lot bigger ( not only in width) but also in height, which never worked until I went into getDomRef in onAfterRendering. 3) All buttons in my app will be changed the same way, which is not, what I want. And this is also the case with input fields.
4) Guidelines ? NONE of our customers were satisfied, as SAP guys came to visit us and presented them.

Comment: 1) Use your own CSS classes 2) Use CSS and not getDomRef 3) Use different CSS classes 4) OK whatever

Comment: 1) Ok, apparently I do something wrong or we both talk about different stuff.

To clarify : 

 Can You post a minimal  example of 2 input fields ( ip1 and ip2 ) where I change the fontsize of ip 1 to 20 but the fontsize of ip2 will remain the default ? Or wait, in Your example, You suffix the class with "input", does that mean... that if I apply my css class and suffix it with input, the class will be inherited down the div, INTO a possible element of type input, and if a certain attribute is found on that element ( e.g. font-size ) , then it will be applied. Is that Your intention ?

Comment: No. You have two inputs. One input has `class="myCustomFontSize"` and the other input doesn't have that class. In your CSS you have `.myCustomFontSize input { font-size: 20px; }`. Problem solved.

Comment: I try it now. And will edit my initial question if feasible

Comment: No, Your idea does not work.  What I did until now, was ( the button example ) , using F12 to find out the inner elements ( in the end there were 2 inner and one outer ), then I created 3 css-classes, where I adjusted the css class to be used in onAfterRendering and by getDomReference I applied each CSS class to the proper element during runtime. This works like a charm. Now I created a new css class ( .testMyBiggerButton Button {
...imagine  merged all contents of those three seperate css classes in here ...} and applied this class directly in the view.
Nothing happened.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yYwdIwZfemGCAx8A

Comment: You did this < .myBiggerButton .sapMBtnInner >. 

EXACTLY this is, what I want to avoid. .....

1) As You said, locally overwriting those standard stuff is not nice, BUT maybe better than using onAfterRendering. I assume, onAfterRendering may have the same culprits in terms of future impact.
2) IS THIS THE RECOMMENDED WAY BY SAP???  If so:
3) Is there a documentation somewhere about the inner architecture of each sapui5-control ?
...it is not normal, that we always need to dig into F12 to find out their inner assigned classes and change /overwrite them locally.

Comment: Well it's not recommended by SAP to change their UI at all (except with a custom theme) but since you don't like what they did you have to deal with the problems. Changing the UI using CSS is a lot better than changing the UI using JS (getDomRef) because that is exactly the purpose of CSS.

Comment: I do use css to change the ui, though I invoke it in classic javascript.

 The mentioned "onRendering approach" is also using nothing else then  this here: 

 innerSpan[0].classList.add("testMyButtonHtmlByDomRef");

getDomRef just simply fetches those inner, wrapped elements, which classes I do not want to override locally ...

Comment: Makes no sense to me. This feels like a jQuery approach. And jQuery is dying out for exactly that reason: Modifying the DOM using JS is outdated. If some other dev takes over your project and wonders "why is the font so big" then they will check the XML view first, the CSS second and the JS last. Or at worst they will never check the JS and assume this is some strange bug. I strongly recommend sticking to standards and best practices. And I honestly don't see why my suggestion is what you want to avoid. But I guess this should be discussed in a separate chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239108/discussion-between-icbytes-and-marc).